# Подключаемые функции не срабатывают все сразу

Tags: php, функции

Есть программа состоящая из трёх файлов:

1. Главный файл ( в нём просто
      перечислены функции из файла с
      функциями)
2. Файл функций( каждая функция
      выполняем свои действия, иногда в
      одной функции может использоваться
      другая функция)
3. Файл с переменными (подключается к
      функциям и к главному файлу)

Через браузер запуская главный файл, после первого обновления страницы исполняется одна функция, после следующего обновления вторая, и т.д. 
Намекните почему так, о чем подумать и в какую сторону?
....Добавил
Кусок главного файла

```
 include_once 'function.php';
         //Переменные
         include_once 'data.php';
         //Подключение к FTP
         $antona_connect = ftp_connect($host, $port);
         if ($antona_connect)
             echo "Соединение установленно";
         //Авторизация на FTP под учетками
         $login = ftp_login($antona_connect, $user,
 $password);
         if ($login)
             echo "<br> Вход выполнен<br>";
         //Режим работы ftp
         ftp_pasv($antona_connect, TRUE);
         //Список файлов на FTP
         $spisok_files = ftp_rawlist($antona_connect,
 $file_remote);
         foreach ($spisok_files as $key => $value) {
             echo $value . "<br>";

             name_byte_remote($value);

         }
         //Список локальных файлов
         $local_scan = scandir($file_local);
         foreach ($local_scan as $key_scan => $value_scan) {
             echo $value_scan;
             if (!is_dir($value_scan)) {

                 //проверяем файл и записываем его функцией
                 ycet_files_local($value_scan);

             }
         }

         //Сравниваем и загружаем если что не так
        sravnenie_remot_local("$name_baza_loc",
 "$baza_remote_er");
        //Удаляем не нужные файлы
        delete_files_ftp_2("$name_baza_loc",
 "$baza_remote_er");

        //Удаляем существующие базы, что бы перезаписать их новыми
        delete_baza();
         ftp_close($antona_connect);
```

Comment: Было бы не плохо код посмотреть. Не обязательно весь. Можно хотя бы отрывки, которые вы считаете показательными.

Comment: То есть я правильно понимаю, что сначала выполняется функция "name_byte_remote" потом "ycet_files_local" и так далее? Как вы узнаете, что они выполняются по одной?

Comment: За выполнением смотрю по проделанным действиям. Допустим первая функция и вторая (они выполняются вместе) создают локальные файлы(текстовые файлы) с списком файлов. Далее обновляю браузер, происходит сравнение строк в этих базах и закачка не совпадающей. Обновляю далее  срабатывает функция "Удаление не нужных" и при следующем обновлении - следующая функция удаляет локальные базы. Если далее обновить, файл начинает работать с начало

Comment: Включите вывод ошибок в браузер. Что говорят ошибки?

Comment: Об ошибках то я и не подумал, включил. Сейчас исправляю варнинги, программа стала работать лучьше. Но ни как не поборю все варнинги.